# All homomorphisms between $Z_{12}$ and $Z_{18}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know homomorphisms between cyclic groups are determined by the mapping of the generator of the domain. Taking the generator 1, I know that since 12*1=0, I need to find multiples of 12 that are 0 mod 18, which are 0,3,6,9, 12, and 15. From this point, are all homomorphisms simply defined as $\phi(g)=ng \space mod \space 18$ for all $g \in Z_{12}$, where $n=\{0,3,6,9,12,15\}$?

Comment: how about $12$ and $15$?

Comment: Are those values taken from $Z_{12}$ or $Z_{18}$?

Comment: From $Z_{18}$, as $\phi(1)$ is in $Z_{18}$.

Comment: Ah, edited original question. Is this now correct?

Comment: Yes. You can also note that $12=-6$ and $15=-3$.